# How may I toggle the autosuggestion feature on/off in zsh?

Tags: zsh, macos

I'm using `zsh` on macOS.

I currently use `zsh` with [this autosuggestions plugin](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) enabled.  I do this by sourcing a script from my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
source ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
```

I sometimes want to turn that autosuggestion feature off or on manually.

How may I do this?

Comment: What are the circumstances under which you do not want to source the `samplefile` file? I.e., what constitutes "sometimes"? Since the file is sourced when you start the terminal, you would have to give whatever necessary commands in a terminal before you start a new one where the file is not to be sourced.

Comment: Does *samplefile* only set variables or execute other tasks ?

Comment: @Kusalananda, the case example; I use zsh-autosuggestions. So there are the code that "source ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh" in .zshrc file. But I sometimes teach programming to student with showing my pc. I don't want to show the autosuggestions for that beginner student. That is way.

Comment: So the question is rather "How may I disable autosuggestions?", or "How may I toggle autosuggestions on/off?", right?

Comment: Yes, it is. "How may I toggle autosuggestions on/off?"

Comment: @MC68020, in my case, samplefile's do autosuggestions.

Comment: @taku I have reformulated the question.  Pleas feel free to edit it if it's not correctly framing your issue.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm new in stackexchange.com but thank you so much for fix my question!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sorry, my explanation was insufficient. The link is https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That plugin adds a [`autosuggest-toggle` widget](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions#key-bindings) to toggle auto-suggestions on/off.

You'd typically bind it to a key or key-combination with:

```
bindkey '^B' autosuggest-toggle
```

For instance to bind it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Though you could also invoke it by hand via the `execute-named-cmd` widget (bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> in Emacs mode and <kbd>:</kbd> in Vi command mode).

A generic approach would be to change your `source` line to:

```
(( $+NO_ZSH_SUGGESTIONS )) ||
  source ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
```

And then:

```
NO_ZSH_SUGGESTIONS=please zsh
```

To start `zsh` with that plugin not enabled.

`$+VAR` expands to 1 if `$VAR` is set, and 0 otherwise, `(( expression ))` returns true if the evaluation of the arithmetic expression yields a number other than 0. Alternatively, with zsh 5.4 or newer, you can use `[[ -v VAR ]]` à la ksh, though `(( $+VAR ))` is more idiomatic in zsh.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem. And I should have read the documentation more carefully. Thank you very much.